# Need to handle duplicate session in jmeter scipt

Tags: jmeter

Below is my Jmeter script flow:

-Thread group
 - Test Plan
 - Login scripts 
   - Http header manager 
   - CSRF authorization using css/Jquery extractor
 - Dashboard 
 - Graph Listener.

**Problem is:** When i run this test plan with 1 user hit, it passes but when i try it with 50 users(more than 1 user)  it fails As in our website Multi sessions are not allowed.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, if your application manages session basing on cookies - it should fix the issue
2. It might be the case your application uses URL parameter for session management - in that case go for [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier)
3. Inspect your script more carefully as it might be not only one dynamic parameter (CSRF token), there could be more parameters requiring [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter). Record the same scenario 2 times using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and compare 2 results scripts. All parameters which are different need to be correlated.

Comment: Dmitri, Actually in our website when any user logged into the website we  store their some session id in Database and if the same user try to logged into some other browser we don't allow him. So the way is When another duplicate session created, we ask to user whether he wants to create a new session or wants to cancel it. I compared all response in normal login or duplicate session login . There  is one parameter (password) is changing. In normal login Password is going in normal format but when any duplicate session continues password goes into encrypted form . so how to crack it out now??